# Why should I use Quartz Scheduler insteade of TimerTask

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm currently developing a web application that fires multiple jobs in the background, allowing web users to logoff and when they come back see the progress of the jobs they fired.

Searching for ways of implementing Jobs and schedule some of them I found examples with Quartz Scheduler and with simple TImerTasks. The thing is I'm not seeing what does Quartz brings to the table that is so different and makes such a difference when compared to simply using Timer and TimerTask java classes.

What are the benefits from using Quartz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quartz adds scheduling, concurrency handling and especially error handling which is quite hard to get right using a simple timerTask.

Also consider capacity configuration (you probably do not want to overload your system with thousands of requests taking all your memory)

See the quartz feature page for some details:

http://quartz-scheduler.org/overview/features

Comment: also add to that, there are plugins in Quartz which job monitoring for you. Quartz is definitely a better implementation of scheduling